# How to pass <a> tag's id="" to a javascript function?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have in a php while loop  :

```
  echo '<li ><a  id="'.$rowmnu2['link'].'" href="#" onclick="passto(this)">'.$rowmnu2['title'].'</a></li>';
```

as you see li will be generated dynamically,  I need to get the  tag's id onclick and pass it to passto() function and then use ajax pass the id to an external php page.

I cant get the id by this code, it shows undefined when i alert it.

is there anything wrong with my code?

please help

Comment: Can you include your JavaScript code?

Comment: Please escape your variables using `htmlspecialchars()` btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. :)

```
<li><a  id="'.$rowmnu2['link'].'" href="#" onclick="passto(this.id)">'.$rowmnu2['title'].'</a></li
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to pass the ID to the function, since it receives the element itself. It can then use the `.id` property accessor to get the ID if it needs it:

```
function passto(elem) {
    alert(elem.id);
    // Do other stuff
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ef6N7/)

Comment: no, alert(elem.id); shows an empty alert

Comment: I added a jsfiddle demo that shows it works.

Comment: well, but not for my case, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd like to show what you tried, since it must be different (and wrong).

Comment: yes the <a tag was wrong, ShreejiShah's suggested way is working for me.

Comment: My answer works with the A tag in your question, his answer requires you to change your HTML. My answer is more general since you can do other things with the element in `passto`, and you don't have to call `getElementById()` to do them. Why pass only the ID when you can pass the element itself?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use jQuery, it makes very little sense to use the `onclick` property directly. Add a class to your links, and then target them like so:

**Markup:**

```
<a id="some-id-1" class="your-neato-class" href="#">Some Neat Title</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a.your-neato-class').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // stop anchor navigation

    // e is a JavaScript element that has some useful properties...
    passTo(e.target.id); 
});
```

As @Jack notes, you could also use `this.id` instead of `e.target.id` - `this` is the DOM element that triggered the event when used inside of an event delegate. See: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: `e.target.id` should be the same as `this.id` here.

Comment: @Jack True. I tend to forget that. Will add it to example.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<li ><a  id="'.$rowmnu2['link'].'" ref="#" onclick="passto('.$rowmnu2['link'].')">'.$rowmnu2['title'].'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  echo '<li ><a  id="'.$rowmnu2['link'].'" href="#" onclick="passto(this.id)">'.$rowmnu2['title'].'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is properly **escape your variables** for HTML usage:

```
printf('<li ><a id="%s" href="#" onclick="passto.call(this, event)">%s</a></li>',
    htmlspecialchars($rowmnu2['link'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($rowmnu2['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
));
```

I've changed the `onclick` attribute like this:

```
passto.call(this, event)
```

When `passto()` is called it will make `this` point to the element itself, e.g.

```
function passto(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(this.id);
}
```